# How to use Sql join to include a specific column from another table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, author and book. Author contains the columns (isbn, name, city, state) and book contains (isbn, title, publisher, category, price, units)

For my assignment I need to output name, city and state (from the author table) and title (from the book table) only for authors from Exeter, NH, Palo Alto, CA, or Arlington, TX.

I can't get join part to work without an error popping up

```
SELECT 
    NAME,
    city,
    state
FROM 
    author

left JOIN book
    USING (title);

WHERE
    (city = 'exeter'AND state = 'NH') OR
    (city = 'arlington'AND state = 'TX') OR 
    (city ='palo alto' AND state = 'CA');
```

Comment: Remove the first semi-colon.

Comment: still says unknown column

Comment: Yes, author has no title column.

Comment: And why does author have an ISBN column?

Comment: the tables were given in the assignment, is there a way to only pull the title column using join?

Comment: @trincot You linked back to This question.

Comment: People check your previous questions... to see how responsive you are. When I answered your previous question [you never came back to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66921753/fetch-execute-cycle-for-lmc-instructions). Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your DBMS?

you need a field to relate the 2 tables, I suppose it is the ISBN that is the only one in common... (although as they already asked you why the ISBN is in the author?)...

```
SELECT a.NAME, b.title,a.city,a.state 
FROM author a 
LEFT JOIN book b 
    ON a.isbn = b.isbn 
WHERE (a.city = 'exeter'AND a.state = 'NH') 
    OR (a.city = 'arlington'AND a.state = 'TX')
    OR (a.city ='palo alto' AND a.state = 'CA')
```

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join should work so long as you join on the columns shared by the tables.

```
SELECT a.name
,a.city
,a.state
,b.title
FROM author a
LEFT OUTER JOIN book b on a.isbn = b.isbn
WHERE
```